# Trying to remove duplicate rows if only column is different

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `real_estate` as

```
name       lat      long    room

house1   26.0351   81.782   3
house1   26.0351   81.782   4
house1   26.0351   81.782   2
house1   26.0351   81.782   2
house2   26.1733   81.7132  2
```

I want to show it as

```
name     lat       long    room


house1   26.0351   81.782  [2,3,4]
house2   26.1733   81.7132  [2]
```

i don't specifically want room to be in array, more like concatenated.

I tried using

```
select name, concat(room,',',room) from `real_estate` group by lat,long;
```

But, it is only concatenating duplicate items.

sorry for confusion, i just started learning sql

Comment: `[1,2,3]` - ?? Where the room=1 is taken, there is no such value in source data? And why room=4 disappears? PS. Does this final value means that you need in JSON array?

Comment: The main problem is MySQL's slack error handling here. MySQL knows a mode in which it doesn't report errors on invalid `GROUP BY` queries. Make sure to always `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` in order to move out of that quirky mode. With ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY set, MySQL should report the error in your query. You group by `lat` and `long`, but you select `name` and `concat(room,',',room)`. This is not allowed, because there can be many different names and rooms per lat and long. (`CONCAT` is not an aggregation function and only deals with the values of one row.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
select name, lat, long, group_concat(distinct room order by room) as rooms
from real_estate
group by name, lat, long
order by name, lat, long;
```

Comment: Thanks, I used @thorsten answer but there were some of duplicates remaining in room column.
So, I used
select name,lat,long,group_concat(distinct rooms) from real_estate group by name;

Comment: Yes, `DISTINCT` in `GROUP_CONCAT` does the task. But you must not remove `lat` and `long` from the `GROUP BY` clause. Otherwise the query gets invalid, as I mentioned in my comment under your request. `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';`to have MySQL warn you of such invalid queries. I've updated the query in my answer.